# Get exception class in kSoap2 on Android

Tags: java, android, android-ksoap2

I've got a fault message. I've successfully caught it on Android. What I would like now, is to get the Class for the Exception that triggered the fault. The message goes like this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Error retrieving user`s [..]</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:exception class="com.example.UserException_Exception" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false" xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/">
               <message>EError retrieving user`s [..]</message>
               <ns2:stackTrace>
                  <ns2:frame class="sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl" file="DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java" line="43" method="invoke"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="java.lang.reflect.Method" file="Method.java" line="601" method="invoke"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1" file="InstanceResolver.java" line="246" method="invoke"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2" file="InvokerTube.java" line="146" method="invoke"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler" file="EndpointMethodHandler.java" line="257" method="invoke"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube" file="SEIInvokerTube.java" line="95" method="processRequest"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="629" method="__doRun"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="588" method="_doRun"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="573" method="doRun"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="470" method="runSync"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="295" method="process"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="515" method="handle"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="285" method="handle"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="143" method="handle"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="155" method="doGet"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="java.lang.Thread" file="Thread.java" line="722" method="run"/>
               </ns2:stackTrace>
            </ns2:exception>
         </detail>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I've removed a part of the trace, because it is not relevant.

This is the code' im using for the transaction:

```
public static Long getCount(String id)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "getCount");
        request.addProperty("id", id);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;

        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

        HttpTransportSE htse = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        htse.call(URL, soapEnvelope, null);

        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        Long count = null;
        try {
            timestampCount = Long.parseLong(response.toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return count;
    }
```

So, how do I go about getting `class="com.ltc.mid.pdf.UserCertificateException_Exception"` from the SoapFault object?

Just to be perfectly clear: I'm looking for either:

- Java code to get the `class` atribute from `<detail><exception>` element
- SOAP parsing code to get `class` atribute from `<detail><exception>` element

Thanks!

Comment: Invocation code has been added.

Comment: use this to solve ur problem...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179246/getting-following-error-while-calling-a-web-service-svc-in-android-through-kso

Comment: @himanshu I fail to see how it solves My problem. I do not need to fix the exception, I need to get the cause for it.

Comment: post ur URL,METHOD_NAME,NAMESPACE and SOAP_ACTION here...the problem might be among 4 of them....

Comment: again @himanshu, there is no problem with the request or the response! None! They work just the way they should! What I need to find out, is how to get the Exception class form the SoapFault object?

Comment: catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           System.out.println("ex1"+e.getClass().toString());
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            System.out.println("ex1"+e.getClass().toString());
        }

Comment: No @himanshu, I don't need to get the class of the SoapFault. I need to get the class of the exception, that triggered the SoapFault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself.

So, taking the format displayed in the question into consideration, this is what works for me:

```
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

        HttpTransportSE htse = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);

        //htse.debug=true; //This directive is helpful while debugging
        try {
            htse.call(URL, soapEnvelope, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (soapEnvelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
            Node details = ((SoapFault) soapEnvelope.bodyIn).detail;
            Element detailElem = (Element) details.getElement(0).getChild(0);
            String exc = detailElem.getName();
            if (exc.equals("SomeSpecificException")) {
                throw new SomeSpecificException();
            }
            throw new Exception("SOAP PROBLEMS!");
        }
```